# TypeScript type 'never' problem. Cant access property due to this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

For the below code, I am unable to access duplicyCheck.name.
the typescript gives an error that says "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'."

```
const duplicacyCheck: userDoc | null = await user.findOne({
                name: name,
                userId: id,
            });
if (duplicacyCheck) {
   console.info(duplicacyCheck.name, "duplicacyCheck");
    }
```

this is my user schema

```
interface userDoc extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string,
    userId: string,
    createdAt: string,
    updatedAt: string,
    version: number,
    createdBy: string,
    updatedBy: string
}
```

The name and userId are required fields in my schema.

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10613) help at all

Answer (score 2):

According to the Mongoose document,

Model.findOne() return << Query >>,
so

```
await user.findOne({
                name: name,
                userId: id,
            });
```

would get a Promise < never >

you should execute it to get the result.

you can execute a query by using Query.exec() like

```
await user.findOne({
                name: name,
                userId: id,
            }).exec();
```

edit:

the [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) also says:

> Although queries are not promises, queries are thenables. That means
> they have a .then() function, so you can use queries as promises with
> either promise chaining or async await
>
> As far as functionality is concerned, these two are equivalent.
> However, we recommend using .exec() because that gives you better
> stack traces.

so recommend to use exec() to find out the actual problem